# bash modify list using operation

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create a function that divides every item in a list by 100 and returns the output as a list. Is there a good way to do something like this?

ex:

```
perform_operation () {
    for num in $1; do
        echo "$num/100" | bc
    done
}

list=$(seq 1 1 10)
new_list=$(perform_operation $list)
echo $new_list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash arrays aren't very straightforward:

https://lukeshu.com/blog/bash-arrays.html

```
perform_operation () {
    { echo scale=2
    for num; do  #`for something; do` is short for `for something in "$@"; do`
        echo "$num/100" 
    done ; } | bc
}

list=( {1..10} )
new_list=( $(perform_operation "${list[@]}") )
printf ' ->%s\n' "${new_list[@]}"
```

Output:

```
 ->.01
 ->.02
 ->.03
 ->.04
 ->.05
 ->.06
 ->.07
 ->.08
 ->.09
 ->.10
```

Launching `bc` (or any program) in a loop is a very bad idea from a performance perspective. Try to invoke as few external programs as possible and pass data to them in batches. That's key to efficient shell scripting.